# Matlab: quickly finding lines with missing semicolons

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to fix all MATLAB mlint messages at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248295/is-there-a-way-to-fix-all-matlab-mlint-messages-at-once)

If one forgets to place a semicolon at the end of a line, Matlab just prints the output of that line to the screen. If one has hundreds of lines of code, it may be very difficult to locate which lines are missing a semi-colon, and one may end up with spurious output polluting the screen.

Is there a way to locate the lines missing a semicolon quickly?

Answer (score 2):

These two might be of some use to you:
[Is there a way to fix all MATLAB mlint messages at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248295/is-there-a-way-to-fix-all-matlab-mlint-messages-at-once)
[Finding Errors, Debugging, and Correcting MATLAB Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-147.html)