# List of MATLAB code analyzer message IDs

Tags: matlab

I'd like to find a list of the message IDs of the built-in code analyzer warning messages used for suppressing those messages either on a single line or in a file (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html#brqxeeu-167)). I know you can search by message ID, but the list in the preferences (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/about-code-analyzer-preferences.html#bs24a39-1)) doesn't actually show the ID itself. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1: (provides only some message tags)

After a while of digging within the MATLAB API, I've come up with the solution you wanted:

```
%// Obtain all definitions
msgDefinitions = com.mathworks.widgets.text.mcode.MLint.getMessageDefinitions();
%// Count definitions
numDefinitions = msgDefinitions.size();

definitionDictionary{numDefinitions,2}=[]; %//Preallocation

for ind1=1:numDefinitions
    definitionDictionary{ind1,1} = char(msgDefinitions.get(ind1-1).toString());
    definitionDictionary{ind1,2} = char(msgDefinitions.get(ind1-1).getTag().toString);
end

%//Optional for convenience:
definitionDictionary = sortrows(definitionDictionary,2);
```

#### Solution 2: (provides Category tags, Syntax Errors, Aesthetics and Readability ...)

An alternative solution (resulting in a longer, but messier list) is

```
allMsgs = mlint('-allmsg', filename);
```

where `filename` can be any valid filename. Category tags may be recognized by a bunch of `=======` in the message.

### Solution comparison:

```
allMsgs = mlint('-allmsg', 'Untitled.m');
msgCodes = regexpi(strtrim({allMsgs.message}'),' ','split'); ...'
msgCodes = cellfun(@(v) v(1), msgCodes(:,1));

alternativeDictionary = sortrows([{allMsgs.message}' msgCodes],2);
```

In MATLAB 2014a the 2nd solution results in a dictionary of size `571`. The 1st solution is of length `477`. Generally speaking, the 2nd solution provides more information.

---

More information is available in the [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/parsing-mlint-code-analyzer-output) article. You can also look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248295/is-there-a-way-to-fix-all-matlab-mlint-messages-at-once/18388118#18388118).

---

> *Below are some details on how I uncovered the 1st solution:*

The internal workflow inside the code checker is as follows:

1. When you right-click on a suppressible warning the Code Checker (AKA *CodeAnalyzer*, *lint*, *mlint*) it, `MKit.class` adds 3 options to suppress warnings that execute the following methods of `CodeAnalyzerUtils.class`:

   - On this line - executes the method `suppressMessage`.
   - In this file - executes the method `suppressAllMessages`.
   - In all files - executes the method `disableMessage`.
2. Having clicked on one of the first two options, the `doInsertSuppression` method is called, adding the string: `" %#ok<" + paramString + '>'`.
3. The mysterious `paramString` is a *private* property named `fTag` that is present within subclasses of `MLint.class` and accessible using a `getTag()` method. Where the tags come from is still unclear.

Sources (in order of appearance):

1. `$matlabroot/java/jar/widgets.jar -> com.mathworks.widgets.text.mcode.MKit`
2. `$matlabroot/java/jar/widgets.jar -> com.mathworks.widgets.text.mcode.analyzer.CodeAnalyzerUtils`
3. `$matlabroot/java/jar/widgets.jar -> com.mathworks.widgets.text.mcode.analyzer.CodeAnalyzerActions`

Comment: <strike>That's a great start, but if I'm understanding the article correctly this will only return a list of the errors / warnings present in a specific file. I was wondering if there was a way to find a master list of message IDs and messages for *all* of the built in errors and warnings.</strike> Never mind, it's in the Undocumented MATLAB article: `allMsgs = mlint('-allmsg', filename)` where `filename` can be any valid filename. This works with the `checkcode` function as well.

Comment: Yea I figured it out, you don't need to use your second solution, the original will work just with a different option (although that returns 585 messages whereas your method only returns 477, not sure why). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wonder why the `-allmsg` solution results in `571` definitions, while the `getMessageDefinitions()` yields only `477`.

Comment: Yea, that's pretty weird. Thanks for spending so much time on this!